# html container scrolling bug

Tags: php, css, html

My html page is working almost as should but i have been scrolling through stackoverflow and can't seems to find any answer specific to mine.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0; 
   }
   h1 {
    font-family: arial;
    color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto; 
   }
   header {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 350%;
    background: black;
    background-image: url(profile_pic.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 20% 70%;
    color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    text-align: center;
    border-spacing: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
   }
   nav {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
   }
   .nav_link {
    flex-grow: 1;
    line-height: 25px;
    
   }
   a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
   }
   a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
   .content {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20% 0% 0% 0%; 
    padding-top: 6%;
   }
   .myPanel {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 999;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 1%;
   }
   .myPanel .heading {
    background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px;
   }
   .myPanel .panelBody {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    background: silver;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
   }
   .myPanel p {
    margin: 3px;
   }
   .myPanel:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px black;
   }
```

```html
<?php include 'head.php';?>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Resume</h1>
 </header>
 <nav>
  <div class="nav_link">
   <a href="index.php"> Home </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_link">
   <a href="resume.php"> Resume </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_link">
   <a href="sideprojects.php"> Side Projects </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_link">
   <a href="aboutme.php"> About Me </a>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">US ARMY NATIONAL GUARD</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
    <p>03/2014 -- Current</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       <p>Crystal River, FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Rank: PV2</ui></br>
        <ui>Diesel Mechanic -- 91H</ui></br>
        <ui>Military Police -- 31b</ui></br>
       </ul>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">LILLYS ON THE LAKE</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>06/2016 -- 02/2017</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       <p>Clermont FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Serving</ui></br>
        <ui>Bartending</ui></br>
        <ui>Service bar</ui></br>
        <ui>Card Holder voids/comps</ui></br>
        <ui>Open/close</ui></br>
        <ui>Food running</ui></br>
        <ui>Expediting</ui></br>
       </ul>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">PANE D'OR</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>08/2015 -- 06/2016</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       <p>Winter Garden FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Baking</ui></br>
        <ui>Pastry</ui></br>
        <ui>Delivering</ui></br>
        <ui>Sales at markets / shop</ui></br>
       </ul>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">Disney</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>06/2015 -- 11/2016</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p class>
       <p>Orlando FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Monorail pilot</ui></br>
        <ui>Platform operator</ui></br>
        <ui>Audience control</ui></br>
        <ui>Customer relations</ui></br>
       </ul>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">PERFORMANCE YEARS GTO</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>01/2012 -- 02/2015</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       <p>Hatfield PA</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Shipping</ui></br>
        <ui>Receiving</ui></br>
        <ui>Pulling/packing/sorting</ui></br>
        <ui>Picker operator</ui></br>
        <ui>Forklift operator</ui></br>
        <ui>Customer service</ui></br>
        <ui>In house sales</ui></br>
        <ui>Show sales</ui></br>
        <ui>Inventory</ui></br>
       </ul>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">GIANT FOODS</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>01/2012 -- 03/2013</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       <p>Montgomeryville PA</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Stocking shelves</ui></br>
        <ui>Rotate merchandise</ui></br>
       </ul>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

so with the fiddle its slightly modified to work on that application. the only differences are that i use some php to form a template for the header and nav bar on my computer.

okay so if you view the fiddle the scroll bar is not only the area i want to scroll but the entire page. i would like to keep the header fixed and have the "body" or for my page the container scroll but not have a full length scroll bar on side of page.

Comment: Why the first panel is child of `div content` but others not?

Comment: i don't know? they all should be !

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: can u do a fiddle here not outside

Comment: 1) You have height set to 100% on the container and the container is only contained by the body

Comment: its just a lot of code it would get messy here but i can edit it all in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position:fixed; to body and overflow-y:scroll to .content

Also don't "close" /br
It's just br or, br/ for extra compatibility.

```
<br/>
```

You also can't nest p tags (have a p tag inside another p tag) or have a list inside a p tag - a list gets its own styling - so get rid of the p around your list+list heading. And you have an extra /div at the end of each myPanel - there should only be three.

Also, 0 values shouldn't have units (eg %) after them. Run your CSS through csslint.net

You've also got some unecessary CSS attributes in there - e.g., your header and nav don't need top/right positioning or position:fixed.

https://jsfiddle.net/Kass_P/kg6uppnm/25/

```
body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0; 
        position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: wow this was very helpful and that is exactly how i wanted the scroll to work tyty

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to do what you said *they all should be !* ...

Then you must fix the height of div content to the screen. In other way if you want your body has not scroll bar, You must set your elements so fixed to the screen and your body has not vertical overflow. Some thing like this:

```
header{height: 60px;}
nav{height: 40px;}
.content{height: calc(100vh - 100px);}
```

Then you can set a vertical scroll bar for div content.

```
#content{overflow-y: auto;}
```

See this simplified of your page:

```css
header {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 60px;
 position: fixed;
 line-height: 350%;
 background: black;
 background-image: url(profile_pic.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right;
 background-size: 20% 70%;
 color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
 text-align: center;
 border-spacing: 5px 10px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
 width: 100%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height: 100%;
 margin-top: 60px;
 height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}

.myPanel {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 999;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 1%;
   }
   .myPanel .heading {
    background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px;
   }
   .myPanel .panelBody {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    background: silver;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
   }
   .myPanel p {
    margin: 3px;
   }
   .myPanel:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px black;
   }
```

```html
  <!--?php include 'head.php';?-->

 <header>
  <h1>Resume</h1>
 </header>
 
 <div class="content">
  <div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">LILLYS ON THE LAKE</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>06/2016 -- 02/2017</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       </p><p>Clermont FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Serving</ui><br>
        <ui>Bartending</ui><br>
        <ui>Service bar</ui><br>
        <ui>Card Holder voids/comps</ui><br>
        <ui>Open/close</ui><br>
        <ui>Food running</ui><br>
        <ui>Expediting</ui><br>
       </ul>
      <p></p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">LILLYS ON THE LAKE</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>06/2016 -- 02/2017</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       </p><p>Clermont FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Serving</ui><br>
        <ui>Bartending</ui><br>
        <ui>Service bar</ui><br>
        <ui>Card Holder voids/comps</ui><br>
        <ui>Open/close</ui><br>
        <ui>Food running</ui><br>
        <ui>Expediting</ui><br>
       </ul>
      <p></p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">LILLYS ON THE LAKE</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>06/2016 -- 02/2017</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       </p><p>Clermont FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Serving</ui><br>
        <ui>Bartending</ui><br>
        <ui>Service bar</ui><br>
        <ui>Card Holder voids/comps</ui><br>
        <ui>Open/close</ui><br>
        <ui>Food running</ui><br>
        <ui>Expediting</ui><br>
       </ul>
      <p></p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">LILLYS ON THE LAKE</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>06/2016 -- 02/2017</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       </p><p>Clermont FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Serving</ui><br>
        <ui>Bartending</ui><br>
        <ui>Service bar</ui><br>
        <ui>Card Holder voids/comps</ui><br>
        <ui>Open/close</ui><br>
        <ui>Food running</ui><br>
        <ui>Expediting</ui><br>
       </ul>
      <p></p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><div class="myPanel">
   <div class="heading">LILLYS ON THE LAKE</div>
    <div class="panelBody">
     <p>06/2016 -- 02/2017</p>
     <div class="showOnHover">
      <p>
       </p><p>Clermont FL</p>
       <ul>
        <ui>Serving</ui><br>
        <ui>Bartending</ui><br>
        <ui>Service bar</ui><br>
        <ui>Card Holder voids/comps</ui><br>
        <ui>Open/close</ui><br>
        <ui>Food running</ui><br>
        <ui>Expediting</ui><br>
       </ul>
      <p></p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i want them to be in % so when you resize the window they actively resize.

Comment: 100vh is 100% of the screen. It is not a fix value. And there is many other ways you can do. I gave you a sample to understand the problem...

Comment: Sorry change #content to `.content`

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `height` from body class.
Set `height:40%` or so for content class.

Also, make all `<div class="myPanel">` inside the `<div class="content">` div
Hope it helps

Comment: why isn't that already happening? do i have to add that div around all myPanels?

Comment: if you analyze your code, you have closed the content div. see the full code below here:

Answer (score 0):

See the full working code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                border: 0; 
            }
            h1 {
                font-family: arial;
                color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
                text-align: center; 
                margin: 0;
                overflow: auto; 
            }
            header {
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0; left: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 30%;
                position: fixed;
                line-height: 350%;
                background: black;
                background-image: url(profile_pic.jpg);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: right;
                background-size: 20% 70%;
                color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
                text-align: center;
                border-spacing: 5px 10px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            nav {
                display: flex;
                text-align: center;
                height: 25px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 30%;
                width: 100%;
                background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
                border: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
            }
            .nav_link {
                flex-grow: 1;
                line-height: 25px;

            }
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
            }
            a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .content {
                width: 100%;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                height: 40%;
                margin: 20% 0% 0% 0%;   
                padding-top: 6%;
            }
            .myPanel {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 999;
                width: 45%;
                margin: 1%;
            }
            .myPanel .heading {
                background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
                border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
                color: white;
                padding: 5px 20px;
            }
            .myPanel .panelBody {
                padding: 3px 20px;
                background: silver;
                border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
            }
            .myPanel p {
                margin: 3px;
            }
            .myPanel:hover {
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px black;
            }

            </style></head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Resume</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav_link">
            <a href="index.php"> Home </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_link">
            <a href="resume.php"> Resume </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_link">
            <a href="sideprojects.php"> Side Projects </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_link">
            <a href="aboutme.php"> About Me </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="myPanel">
            <div class="heading">US ARMY NATIONAL GUARD</div>
                <div class="panelBody">
                <p>03/2014 -- Current</p>
                    <div class="showOnHover">
                        <p>
                            <p>Crystal River, FL</p>
                            <ul>
                                <ui>Rank: PV2</ui></br>
                                <ui>Diesel Mechanic -- 91H</ui></br>
                                <ui>Military Police -- 31b</ui></br>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="myPanel">
            <div class="heading">LILLYS ON THE LAKE</div>
                <div class="panelBody">
                    <p>06/2016 -- 02/2017</p>
                    <div class="showOnHover">
                        <p>
                            <p>Clermont FL</p>
                            <ul>
                                <ui>Serving</ui></br>
                                <ui>Bartending</ui></br>
                                <ui>Service bar</ui></br>
                                <ui>Card Holder voids/comps</ui></br>
                                <ui>Open/close</ui></br>
                                <ui>Food running</ui></br>
                                <ui>Expediting</ui></br>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="myPanel">
            <div class="heading">PANE D'OR</div>
                <div class="panelBody">
                    <p>08/2015 -- 06/2016</p>
                    <div class="showOnHover">
                        <p>
                            <p>Winter Garden FL</p>
                            <ul>
                                <ui>Baking</ui></br>
                                <ui>Pastry</ui></br>
                                <ui>Delivering</ui></br>
                                <ui>Sales at markets / shop</ui></br>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="myPanel">
            <div class="heading">Disney</div>
                <div class="panelBody">
                    <p>06/2015 -- 11/2016</p>
                    <div class="showOnHover">
                        <p class>
                            <p>Orlando FL</p>
                            <ul>
                                <ui>Monorail pilot</ui></br>
                                <ui>Platform operator</ui></br>
                                <ui>Audience control</ui></br>
                                <ui>Customer relations</ui></br>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="myPanel">
            <div class="heading">PERFORMANCE YEARS GTO</div>
                <div class="panelBody">
                    <p>01/2012 -- 02/2015</p>
                    <div class="showOnHover">
                        <p>
                            <p>Hatfield PA</p>
                            <ul>
                                <ui>Shipping</ui></br>
                                <ui>Receiving</ui></br>
                                <ui>Pulling/packing/sorting</ui></br>
                                <ui>Picker operator</ui></br>
                                <ui>Forklift operator</ui></br>
                                <ui>Customer service</ui></br>
                                <ui>In house sales</ui></br>
                                <ui>Show sales</ui></br>
                                <ui>Inventory</ui></br>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="myPanel">
            <div class="heading">GIANT FOODS</div>
                <div class="panelBody">
                    <p>01/2012 -- 03/2013</p>
                    <div class="showOnHover">
                        <p>
                            <p>Montgomeryville PA</p>
                            <ul>
                                <ui>Stocking shelves</ui></br>
                                <ui>Rotate merchandise</ui></br>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```